# PHP - Extract value from string

Tags: php

I have several strings that have been pulled using cURL from another website. The string itself contains the entire pages HTML structure, however inside each page there is a paragraph as outlined below:

`<p>Displaying 1-15 of 15 items beginning with A</p>`
`<p>Displaying 1-20 of 33 items beginning with B</p>`

What I need to do is just extract the total values from these strings (`15` and `33` in the above case).

I'm not sure what the best method to extract the values is.

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm betting that someone will provide an answer soon that uses a regular expression to extract the totals

Comment: Oh, really? I've just did. :)

Comment: @Tomasz hehe, thanks for validating my theory :-) +1 for you.

Comment: Thanks, @andyb. This was the first that came to my mind - the simplest [and somewhat the fastest] I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A brute force approach:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

```
preg_match_all('/<p>Displaying (\d+)-(\d+) of (\d+) items beginning with ([A-Z]+)</p>/', $subject, $matches);
```

Comment: No problem, always at your service.

Answer (score 4):

Create a regular expression;

```
$regex = "/Displaying 1-([0-9]+) of ([0-9]+) items begginning with/";
preg_match($regex,$resultfromcurl,$match);
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a day late and a dollar short, but here are my 2 cents: This will parse the html from a file, grab the paragraphs, find the matches, and throw all of the relevant values into an array for later use.

```
<?php

// Open your document
$doc = new DOMDocument();

// Parse the HTML
$doc->loadHTMLFile("html_doc.html");

// Find the paragraphs and loop through them
$paras = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');

// Initialize value array
$range = array(); 

// Extract the value and put them in a useful data structure
for ($i = 0; $i < $paras->length; $i++) {
    $subject = $paras->item($i)->nodeValue;
    preg_match('/Displaying (\d+)-(\d+) of (\d+) items beginning with ([A-Z]+)/', $subject, $matches);
    $range[$matches[4]] = array(
        'start' => $matches[1],
        'stop'  => $matches[2],
        'total' => $matches[3]
    );
}

foreach ($range as $begin => $values) {
    echo "\n$begin\n";
    echo "start: " . $values['start'] . "\n";
    echo "stop: " . $values['stop'] . "\n";
    echo "total: " . $values['total'] . "\n";
    echo "------\n";
}
```